# How to make Emacs edit JSON data in `json-mode`?

Tags: json, auto-mode-alist

I am working with `GNU Emacs 23.1.1`. When working with a .json file it is treated in the Fundamental mode:

[image]

How can I have the json file treated in the json mode?

I note that `GNU Emacs 24.3.1` opens json files as Javascript which already allows formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make emacs automatically open binary files in hexl-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/make-emacs-automatically-open-binary-files-in-hexl-mode)

Comment: @Drew the difference between my question and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/make-emacs-automatically-open-binary-files-in-hexl-mode is technically involved therefore my question deserves a separate answer.

Comment: What have you tried to do?  Explain why using Emacs-24.3 in javascript-mode is not good enough

Comment: Why not upgrade?  Your version of Emacs is truly ancient.

Comment: @Qudit, I am working on a system where I have no administrative rights.

Comment: @Stefan, I don't know yet if the Javascript mode truly matches up to the Json mode. At least it allows some formatting.

Comment: @Viesturs: "I don't know yet if" makes it sound like you haven't encountered any problem (yet), which makes me think there is no real question.

Comment: @Viesturs You could still install it as a container, an appimage or compile it from source yourself without root.

Comment: @Viesturs - When installing or upgrading emacs on host is not a viable option, I use emacs+tramp on my local machine to login to remote host and edit the file remotely. For example, If I do `C-x C-f /scp:username@remote-hostname:/path/to/file RET` then emacs will login via SCP to remote-hostname as username and open /path/to/file inside emacs on my local machine. I use this feature everyday.

Answer (score 2):

Install [json-mode](https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode) might be the simplest.

In my set up (I use straight.el)

simply

```
(use-package json-mode)
```