# How can I make sure that Emacs opens files with extension `*.rec` as normal text files?

Tags: find-file, auto-mode-alist

How can I make sure that Emacs opens files with extension `*.rec` as normal text files?

When I try to open a file with the extnsion `*.rec`, I get the error message `Running someFile.rec...done` without the file being opened.

[image: Screenshot]

I assume that `rec-mode` is not installed because its status is `Available from gnu` (see below).

[image: Status of the rec-mode package]

What can I do in order for Emacs to open `*.rec` files as plain, normal text files?

Comment: Check the variable `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make emacs automatically open binary files in hexl-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/make-emacs-automatically-open-binary-files-in-hexl-mode)

Comment: @Drew My rec files are not binary, they are text files with the extension `rec`.

Comment: That doesn't matter. `auto-mode-alist` is for any extension and mode. Please consult the doc, and please read that duplicate Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell Emacs that `*.rec` files should be opened in `text-mode`:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rec\\'" . text-mode))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `M-x find-file-literally` Emacs will use `fundamental-mode` as the major mode. Then change to txt mode.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make Org mode open files in links (`[[file:someFile.rec][Rec file]]`) in the fundamental or text mode?

Comment: Check the variable `auto-mode-alist`.